# OTRS .opm package installation fails with error?

Tags: 12.04, apache2, configuration, perl, otrs

Scenario:
   I have downloaded the complete installation file of ITSM after a successful installation of OTRS/HelpDesk.

When i go to admin panal @ `http://localhost/otrs/index.pl?Action=AdminPackageManager` and give a path of the OPM file downloaded of all ITSM packages and click install it gives me a below error.

```
Oops! An Error occurred.
Error Message: 413 Request entity too large - POST_MAX=16384KB
Please contact your administrator.
You can  Send a bugreport or go back to the previous page.

Error Details:
Backend ERROR: OTRS-CGI-10 Perl: 5.14.2 OS: linux Time: Thu Oct 17 11:00:45 2013 Message: 
413 Request entity too large - POST_MAX=16384KB Traceback (19902): Module:             `Kernel::System::Web::InterfaceAgent::Run (v1.58.2.1) Line: 150 Module:    ` `ModPerl::ROOT::ModPerl::Registry::usr_share_otrs_bin_cgi_2dbin_index_2epl::handler (unknown `    `version) Line: 46 Module: (eval) (v1.89.2.1) Line: 204 Module: ModPerl::RegistryCooker::run     (v1.89.2.1) Line: 204 Module: ModPerl::RegistryCooker::default_handler (v1.89.2.1) Line: 170     Module: ModPerl::Registry::handler (v1.99) Line: 31'
```

for the same error I also have attached a screenshot below:

[image]

System Configuration:

Linux opennms-dns 3.5.0-23-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 25 17:13:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

OTRS:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you're trying to upload is a little more than the 16MB that is allowed by your configuration. 
You're running a pretty old OTRS version, 3.0.11. In newer versions the default value has been set to 24M.

To change it manually, go to Admin > SysConfig > Framework > Core::Web and set  `WebMaxFileUpload` to 24000000

Please note that you might also need to increase max_packet_size in /etc/mysql/my.cnf from 16M to 24M and restart mysql using `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`.